# Print to fax PHP

Tags: php, fax

I am trying to figure out a way to use the print to a local fax machine with PHP. Is there a way to have the print to fax utility in windows (7) to fax a document called with PHP. Maybe some how diving into the windows API? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PHP actually has functions to use a printer directly from a script. See this [link](http://my.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php). I'm not sure whether this works for you to print to the Fax printer.

Do you generate a document first that you want to print afterwards, e.g. a PDF file? If this is your use case, you could also store those documents to some folder where another script (shell, cmd, etc...) checks for new files regularly and sends them to the printer.

Comment: I can send something to a printer, but I need to be able to give it the fax number. I don't know the parameters

Comment: I don't know how to do that. It seems there's a number of fax solution providers out there. Some of them accept a fax as an e-mail and then send it to the number you specify. See here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?threadid=262403

Comment: I am hoping to be able to use our local machine. I am wondering if there is a way to tap into the windows com api

Comment: Look at this example of sending a Fax via Windows using VB Script: http://sandlerco.com/VBScript.htm